# android bad token exception unable to add window in WindowManager service

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open video player in windowManager service. If i use image instead of 'VideoView', Everything works fine. But if i use VideoView then i am getting this exception.

```
01-06 12:17:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(1129): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
    01-06 12:17:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:563)
    01-06 12:17:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:269)
    01-06 12:17:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    01-06 12:17:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
    01-06 12:17:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
    01-06 12:17:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.widget.VideoView$4.onError(VideoView.java:421)
    01-06 12:17:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(1129):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2022)
```

I searched on google and i fixed all the things, But still not working.

Here is my code.

ChatHeadService

```
    package henrychuang.tw.chatheadmsg;     
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.VideoView;

    public class ChatHeadService extends Service {      
        private WindowManager windowManager;
        private RelativeLayout chatheadView, removeView;
        private LinearLayout txtView, txt_linearlayout;
        private ImageView   removeImg;
        private VideoView chatheadImg;
        private TextView  txt1;


        private int x_init_cord, y_init_cord, x_init_margin, y_init_margin, iLife = 0;  
        private Point szWindow = new Point();
        private boolean isLeft = true;

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate();
            Log.d(Utility.LogTag, "ChatHeadService.onCreate()");

            windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            removeView = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.remove, null);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams paramRemove = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            paramRemove.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

            removeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            removeImg = (ImageView)removeView.findViewById(R.id.remove_img);
            windowManager.addView(removeView, paramRemove);


            chatheadView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.chathead, null);
            chatheadImg = (VideoView)chatheadView.findViewById(R.id.chathead_img);      
            String path="http://10.0.2.2/SILLI.mpg";
             Uri uri=Uri.parse(path);
             chatheadImg.setVideoURI(uri);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(szWindow);
            } else {
                int w = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                int h = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
                szWindow.set(w, h);
            }

            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            params.x = 0;
            params.y = 0;
            windowManager.addView(chatheadView, params);
            /*
            Handler handler_longClick = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable_longClick = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d(Utility.LogTag, "Into runnable_longClick");
                update();
                }
            };*/


            chatheadView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                long time_start = 0, time_end = 0;
                boolean isLongclick = false, inBounded = false;
                int remove_img_width = 0, remove_img_height = 0;

                Handler handler_longClick = new Handler();
                Runnable runnable_longClick = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d(Utility.LogTag, "Into runnable_longClick");

                        isLongclick = true;
                        removeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        chathead_longclick();
                    }
                };

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) chatheadView.getLayoutParams();

                    int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                    int x_cord_Destination, y_cord_Destination;             

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                        time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        handler_longClick.postDelayed(runnable_longClick, 600);

                        remove_img_width = removeImg.getLayoutParams().width;
                        remove_img_height = removeImg.getLayoutParams().height;

                        x_init_cord = x_cord;
                        y_init_cord = y_cord;

                        x_init_margin = layoutParams.x;
                        y_init_margin = layoutParams.y;

                        if(txtView != null){
                            txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int x_diff_move = x_cord - x_init_cord;
                        int y_diff_move = y_cord - y_init_cord;                 

                        x_cord_Destination = x_init_margin + x_diff_move;
                        y_cord_Destination = y_init_margin + y_diff_move;                   

                        if(isLongclick){
                            int x_bound_left = (szWindow.x - removeView.getWidth()) / 2 - 250;
                            int x_bound_right = (szWindow.x + removeView.getWidth()) / 2 + 100;

                            int y_bound_top = szWindow.y - (removeView.getHeight() + getStatusBarHeight()) - 200;

                            if((x_cord_Destination >= x_bound_left && x_cord_Destination <= x_bound_right) && y_cord_Destination >= y_bound_top){
                                inBounded = true;

                                layoutParams.x = (szWindow.x - chatheadView.getWidth()) / 2;
                                layoutParams.y = szWindow.y - (removeView.getHeight() + getStatusBarHeight()) + 70;                 

                                if(removeImg.getLayoutParams().height == remove_img_height){
                                    removeImg.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (remove_img_height * 1.5);
                                    removeImg.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (remove_img_width * 1.5);

                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams param_remove = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) removeView.getLayoutParams();
                                    int x_cord_remove = (int) ((szWindow.x - (remove_img_height * 1.5)) / 2);
                                    int y_cord_remove = (int) (szWindow.y - ((remove_img_width * 1.5) + getStatusBarHeight() ));
                                    param_remove.x = x_cord_remove;
                                    param_remove.y = y_cord_remove;

                                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(removeView, param_remove);
                                }


                                windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, layoutParams);
                                break;
                            }else{
                                inBounded = false;
                                removeImg.getLayoutParams().height = remove_img_height;
                                removeImg.getLayoutParams().width = remove_img_width;

                                WindowManager.LayoutParams param_remove = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) removeView.getLayoutParams();
                                int x_cord_remove = (szWindow.x - removeView.getWidth()) / 2;
                                int y_cord_remove = szWindow.y - (removeView.getHeight() + getStatusBarHeight() );

                                param_remove.x = x_cord_remove;
                                param_remove.y = y_cord_remove;

                                windowManager.updateViewLayout(removeView, param_remove);
                            }

                        }


                        layoutParams.x = x_cord_Destination;
                        layoutParams.y = y_cord_Destination;                    

                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, layoutParams);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        isLongclick = false;
                        removeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        removeImg.getLayoutParams().height = remove_img_height;
                        removeImg.getLayoutParams().width = remove_img_width;
                        handler_longClick.removeCallbacks(runnable_longClick);

                        if(inBounded){
                            if(MyDialog.active){
                                MyDialog.myDialog.finish();
                            }                       

                            stopService(new Intent(ChatHeadService.this, ChatHeadService.class));
                            inBounded = false;
                            break;
                        }


                        int x_diff = x_cord - x_init_cord;
                        int y_diff = y_cord - y_init_cord;

                        if(x_diff < 5 && y_diff < 5){
                            time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            if((time_end - time_start) < 300){
                                chathead_click();
                            }
                        }


                        x_cord_Destination = x_init_margin + x_diff;
                        y_cord_Destination = y_init_margin + y_diff;

                        int x_start;
                        x_start = x_cord_Destination;                   


                        int BarHeight =  getStatusBarHeight();
                        if (y_cord_Destination < 0) {
                            y_cord_Destination = 0;
                        } else if (y_cord_Destination + (chatheadView.getHeight() + BarHeight) > szWindow.y) {
                            y_cord_Destination = szWindow.y - (chatheadView.getHeight() + BarHeight );
                        }                           
                        layoutParams.y = y_cord_Destination;

                        inBounded = false;
                        resetPosition(x_start);

                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.d(Utility.LogTag, "chatheadView.setOnTouchListener  -> event.getAction() : default");
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });


            txtView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.txt, null);
            txt1 = (TextView) txtView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            txt_linearlayout = (LinearLayout)txtView.findViewById(R.id.txt_linearlayout);


            WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsTxt = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            paramsTxt.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

            txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            windowManager.addView(txtView, paramsTxt);

        }


        private void resetPosition(int x_cord_now) {
            int w = chatheadView.getWidth();

            if(x_cord_now == 0 || x_cord_now == szWindow.x - w){

            } else if(x_cord_now + w / 2<= szWindow.x / 2){     
                isLeft = true;          
               // moveToLeft(x_cord_now);           

            } else if(x_cord_now + w / 2 > szWindow.x / 2){         
                isLeft = false;         
              //  moveToRight(x_cord_now);

            }

        }
         private void moveToLeft(int x_cord_now){

                final int x = x_cord_now;
                new CountDownTimer(500, 5) {
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) chatheadView.getLayoutParams();
                    public void onTick(long t) {
                        long step = (500 - t)/5;
                        mParams.x = (int)(double)bounceValue(step,x);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, mParams);
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        mParams.x = 0;
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, mParams);
                    }
                }.start();
         }
         private  void moveToRight(int x_cord_now){
                final int x = x_cord_now;
                new CountDownTimer(500, 5) {
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) chatheadView.getLayoutParams();
                    public void onTick(long t) {
                        long step = (500 - t)/5;
                        mParams.x = szWindow.x + (int)(double)bounceValue(step,x) - chatheadView.getWidth();
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, mParams);
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        mParams.x = szWindow.x - chatheadView.getWidth();
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, mParams);
                    }
                }.start();
            }

         private double bounceValue(long step, long scale){
                double value = scale * java.lang.Math.exp(-0.055 * step) * java.lang.Math.cos(0.08 * step);
                return value;
            }

         private int getStatusBarHeight() {
            int statusBarHeight = (int) Math.ceil(25 * ChatHeadService.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            return statusBarHeight;
        }

        private void chathead_click(){
            if(MyDialog.active){
                MyDialog.myDialog.finish();
            }else{
                Intent it = new Intent(ChatHeadService.this,MyDialog.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(it);
            }

        }

        private void chathead_longclick(){
            Log.d(Utility.LogTag, "Into ChatHeadService.chathead_longclick() ");

            WindowManager.LayoutParams param_remove = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) removeView.getLayoutParams();
            int x_cord_remove = (szWindow.x - removeView.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y_cord_remove = szWindow.y - (removeView.getHeight() + getStatusBarHeight() );

            param_remove.x = x_cord_remove;
            param_remove.y = y_cord_remove;

            windowManager.updateViewLayout(removeView, param_remove);
        }

        private void showMsg(String sMsg){
            if(txtView != null && chatheadView != null ){
                Log.d(Utility.LogTag, "ChatHeadService.showMsg -> sMsg=" + sMsg);
                txt1.setText(sMsg);
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);

                WindowManager.LayoutParams param_chathead = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) chatheadView.getLayoutParams();
                WindowManager.LayoutParams param_txt = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) txtView.getLayoutParams();

                txt_linearlayout.getLayoutParams().height = chatheadView.getHeight();       
                txt_linearlayout.getLayoutParams().width = szWindow.x / 2;

                if(isLeft){                             
                    param_txt.x = param_chathead.x + 100;
                    param_txt.y = param_chathead.y;

                    txt_linearlayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                }else{              
                    param_txt.x = param_chathead.x - szWindow.x / 2;
                    param_txt.y = param_chathead.y;

                    txt_linearlayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                }

                txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(txtView, param_txt);

                myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 4000);

            }               

        }

        Handler myHandler = new Handler();
        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(txtView != null){
                    txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
            if(bd != null){
                final String sMsg = bd.getString(Utility.EXTRA_MSG);
                Log.e(Utility.LogTag, "ChatHeadService.onStartCommand() -> EXTRA_MSG=" + sMsg);

                if(iLife > 0)
                    showMsg(sMsg);
                else{
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            showMsg(sMsg);
                        }
                    }, 300);
                }
            }

            iLife++;
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();

            if(chatheadView != null){
                windowManager.removeView(chatheadView);
            }

            if(txtView != null){
                windowManager.removeView(txtView);
            }

            if(removeView != null){
                windowManager.removeView(removeView);
            }

        }


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(Utility.LogTag, "ChatHeadService.onBind()");
            return null;
        }


    }
```

Main

```
    package henrychuang.tw.chatheadmsg;
    import henrychuang.tw.chatheadmsg.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    public class Main extends Activity {
        public static Button btnStartService, btnShowMsg;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            btnStartService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStartService);
            btnShowMsg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMsg);

            btnStartService.setOnClickListener(lst_StartService);
            btnShowMsg.setOnClickListener(lst_ShowMsg);
        }


        Button.OnClickListener lst_StartService = new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startService(new Intent(Main.this, ChatHeadService.class));         
            }

        };


        Button.OnClickListener lst_ShowMsg = new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
                String str = "test by henry  " + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(now);

                Intent it = new Intent(Main.this, ChatHeadService.class);
                it.putExtra(Utility.EXTRA_MSG, str);
                startService(it);
            }

        };
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
        }


    }
```

MyDialog

```
package henrychuang.tw.chatheadmsg;
import henrychuang.tw.chatheadmsg.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MyDialog extends Activity {
    public static boolean active = false;
    public static Activity myDialog;

    EditText edt;
    Button btn;
    View top;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialog_edt);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn);
        top = (View)findViewById(R.id.dialog_top);

        myDialog = MyDialog.this;

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String str = edt.getText().toString();
                if(str.length() > 0){
//                  ChatHeadService.showMsg(MyDialog.this, str);
                    Intent it = new Intent(MyDialog.this, ChatHeadService.class);
                    it.putExtra(Utility.EXTRA_MSG, str);
                    startService(it);
                }
            }
        });


        top.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        active = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        active = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        active = false;
    }



}
```

Utility

```
    package henrychuang.tw.chatheadmsg;


    public class Utility {
        public static String LogTag = "henrytest";
        public static String EXTRA_MSG = "extra_msg";

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without reading all of your code: The error message is most likely saying you have used the Application somewhere instead of the Activity, for something that needs a Context.

(Ref: My own experience and [stackoverflow.com/questions/28346458/progressbar-in-asynchtask-causes-crash-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346458/progressbar-in-asynchtask-causes-crash-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-n))